# pariwise comparison when test of effects not significant

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss, marginal-effect

I am making a full factorial repeated measure test in SPSS, and the Test of Within-Subjects Effects/multivariate tests are all non-significant.

In this case would estimated marginal means pairwise comparison make sense since I would use a model that is not significant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**  You should take at 'face value' the ANOVA result that the factor does not contain significant differences. Although not common, it could happen that an *ad hoc* "test" would "find" a bogus significant difference between two levels of a non-significant factor.

Depending on circumstances, this might be due to using a different measure of differences than in the main ANOVA or it might be a chance 'false discovery' due to multiple testing of the same data.

Properly done, you should *not even look* for such  differences, but if you do look and think you have found something, you should ignore your mistake.

Comment: Ok basically nothing be said about the data since no factors are significant? What if I fit a submodel and something is significant. Would this be bad practice as the full factorial is not signf?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by fitting a submodel. If it is truly a sub-model, why was significance not found initially? Even if the main model is significant (say barely at 5%), all _ad hoc_ tests should be use a method that protects against false discovery (perhaps requiring significance at 2% or 1% level). // If you do 20 independent _ad hoc_ tests at 5%, chances are one will reject.

Comment: for example the model where nothing is significant has 12 parameters while the submodel has 10 of the 12 parameters but shows something is significant

Comment: On what basis did you choose those 10, in particular, out of 12. There are ${12\choose 10} = 66$ possible subsets of 10, why that particular one?